# Remove/hide TinyMCE resize drag handles on image elements

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMCE. In IE9, when the user adds an image, they see resize handles around the image.

For example, look at the squares around the figure image:

[image]

[image]

They don't show up in any other browser (chrome, safari, firefox).

How can I remove/hide the resize drag handles in IE?

Thanks!

---

Things I've tried but didn't work:

Disable object resize in the options:
`tinyMCE.init({object_resizing:false})`

Setting CSS resize property to none: `* { resize: none }`

Comment: Hm, why did this question get a down vote. Did I do something wrong? Perhaps I can add details?

Comment: Maybe because the question was not formatted well and you didn't add your code, I didn't down vote but I've edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue yesterday, it was working fine on Chrome/FF but in IE 11/10/9/8 I was seeing resizable icons, same as your case.

I had a div with some classname, so I solved it by:

```
var mydiv = $('#div.classname');
var parentElement = $('iframe').contents().find('body');

mydiv.mouseenter(function(e) {
     parentElement.Contents.attr('contentEditable', false);
}).mouseout(function(e) {
     parentElement.Contents.attr('contentEditable', true);
});
```

Basically you have to disable the `contenteditable` property if you don't want to see the re-sizable options. So just use jQuery to select the image or any other element you want and then make this property false.

Since you have an image you can use

```
var ifr_body = $('iframe').contents().find('body');    
$('#youreditorid').contents().find('img.classnameofimage').hover(
    function() {
        ifr_body.attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    },  function() {
        ifr_body.attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    }
);
```

I had to do this action on `hover`, your situation may vary, just remember that you have to make `contenteditable` `false`, that's it. Choose your own action/selectors.

Also see: [TinyMCE: Disable 'resizable' function for specific div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243512/tinymce-disable-resizable-function-for-specific-div/)